# concat the two id came from database in ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

i am having trouble in concating the value of my two ID's from database to generate a new ID and use it to save again in Database. I am using codeigniter and i want something a good technique/way to concat for better result or maybe faster. 
Also i am having a problem, whenever there is a value in my database, i cannot increment my ID by having +1. I got an output of `1-undefine-1`

Here is my ajax:

```
function getcheckupID() {

var init = 0;
var value = $('#clinicID').html();

  $.ajax ({
    url: siteurl+"myclinic/getcheckID",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.length>0) {
          $('#checkID').text(value+"-"+data[0]['clinic_id']+1);
          $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');
        }
        else {
          $('#checkID').text(value+"-"+init);
          $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');
        }
    }
  }) 
}


   function get_clinicID() {
  $("#clinicID").empty();
  $.ajax({
        url: siteurl+"myclinic/get_clinicID",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#clinicID').text(data[0]['clinic_id']);
        }
  });
}
```

i check the records in my DB using this `if(data.length>0)` then if i got record, i go get the data and +1 it. I got a value of undefined, but if it goes to else, it outputs bad, because whenever i refresh it. sometimes it only outputs - 0, where i want is 1-0. Then refresh it again. How can i concat safely ? Is it an issue in ajax ?. making slow ?

Here is my controller for it :

```
public function getcheckID() {
        $checkID = $this->clinic_model->checkupID();
        echo json_encode($checkID); 
    }
```

My Model :

```
public function checkupID() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT tbl_check_up.check_up_id FROM tbl_check_up');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: `console.log(data)`. The structure probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @aynber why i got different output whenever i refresh it ? sometimes its working fine, but sometimes it doesn't concat ? is it a problem with ajax ?